# How to get has_secure_password to work in production?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, security, deployment

I'm using has_secure_password in a new application and it works great locally. However, when I deploy to our server and try to run it I get the following error message:

> undefined local variable or method `has_secure_password' for
>   WorkerLogin:Class

I did a `bundle install` and everything so I'm not sure what's missing. I'm on ruby 1.9.2p290 but I don't think that would be the problem.

Thoughts?

Comment: Could you provide the WorkingLogin class, and the version of rails you are using?, after checking the bcrypt-ruby gem, as the answer below says.

Comment: I hate it when I ask a question and then later realize it's because of my own stupidity and nobody could have possibly known the solution.

Answer (score 4):

I eventually realized I didn't have my latest code pushed to GitHub yet when I did the Capistrano deployment. I had `include ActiveModel::SecurePassword` added to my WorkerLogin class but not checked in. This line is required because I'm using MongoDB/MongoMapper and it doesn't automatically include `ActiveModel::SecurePassword` like ActiveRecord does.

Answer (score 2):

In Gemfile uncomment or add this line:

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
```

and run bundle install

Comment: I eventually figured out my own issue but this is a good tip for others using SecurePassword. Thanks.